# Reading XML or objects from a Web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

This is my first time working with webservices and I am a bit  lost. 
I successfully called the functions, but I only can get one value from
the service. I read that the easiest way is to read xml or create objects
and then call their values. Currently I use functions that return the desired 
value but I need to call them 3 times to get all the data witch is a waste of time
and resources. I tried to call the service with the URL and use it as a website
or getting the service to work the same way without importing into the program.
The thing is that i cant find a way to pass the values into the url, because of that
i get only blank pages. What is the fastest way to get my data from the services?
I need city name, temperature and a flag if the city is valid. I need to pass the zip
code to the service.

Thank you.

My current code

wetther.Weather wether = new wetther.Weather();

```
        string farenhait = wether.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip).Temperature;
        string city = wether.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip).City;
        bool correct = wether.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip).Success;
```

I tried it that way

```
// Retrieve XML document  
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=94704");  

// Skip non-significant whitespace  
reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant;  

// Read nodes one at a time  
while (reader.Read())  
{  
    // Print out info on node  
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", reader.NodeType.ToString(), reader.Name);  
}
```

This one works for the yahoo page but not for mine.

I need to use this webservice -> http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx

Comment: You are consuming the webservice in C# right? Why don't you add web service reference [How to: Add a Reference to a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)

Comment: @Anuraj actualy at the moment i am dooing it that way. I just dont know how to get the xml out. I can only get a value per connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to add a reference to the web service into your project. From here you will be able to query the web service like it was a class in your project. Right click on your project in the `Solution Explorer` then click `Add Service Reference`. You can then copy and paste the webservice URL into the dialog.

Then you can query it as such...

```
Weather.WeatherSoapClient w = new Weather.WeatherSoapClient();

Weather.ForecastReturn f = w.GetCityForecastByZIP("12345");

string farenhait = f.Temperature;
string city = f.City;
bool correct = f.Success;
```

Basically what you were doing is triggering the HTTP request every single time. What you needed to do was get the single request into one object (`f`) that you can then retreive the properties of.

Comment: I did it that way. But then i call it that way.

string farenhait = wether.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip).Temperature;
            string city = wether.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip).City;

how should i call it that i dont need to call it 2x ?

Answer (score 1):

```
WeatherServiceRef.WeatherSoapClient weatherSoapClient = new WeatherSoapClient("WeatherSoap");

WeatherServiceRef.ForecastReturn forecastRet = weatherSoapClient.GetCityForecastByZIP("90210"); //enter valid zip string

foreach (Forecast forecast in forecastRet.ForecastResult)    
    {
    Console.WriteLine("\nForecast {0}", forecast.WeatherID);
    Console.WriteLine ("Temperature (morning low): {0}", forecast.Temperatures.MorningLow);
    Console.WriteLine("Temperature (morning high): {0}", forecast.Temperatures.DaytimeHigh);
    Console.WriteLine("Probability of precipitation (daytime): {0}", forecast.ProbabilityOfPrecipiation.Daytime)
    //insert other code to retrieve values here
   }

Console.ReadLine();
```

You can add the service reference to the web service using the right-click add service. I have called the service reference WeatherServiceRef in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I used @MichaelCoxes awser and came up whit thi. Works perfectly

```
        degress.TempConvert todegress = new degress.TempConvert();
        wetther.Weather wether = new wetther.Weather();

        wetther.WeatherReturn f = wether.GetCityWeatherByZIP("10001");

        string city = f.City;
        bool correct = f.Success;
        string farenhait = f.Temperature;
```